# Warehouse - one dimension for multiple dates?

Tags: date, dimension, snowflake-schema

This is example of simple warehouse:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Snowflake-schema-example.png

If in Fact_Sales there is still Date2_ID, Date3_ID would these two dates be related with the same Dim_Date dimension or I would have to create Dim_Date2 and Dim_Date3 dimensions (with respective snowflake schema)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could use the same dimension for dates, since every row has a unique id. See [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-data-warehouse-cribsheet/#tenth) for explanation (scroll to "The date dimension");

Comment: Thank you, this is a great article!